# How can I create a classifier using the feature map of a CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

I intend to make a classifier using the feature map obtained from a CNN. Can someone suggest how I can do this?

Would it work if I first train the CNN using +ve and -ve samples (and hence obtain the weights), and then every time I need to classify an image, I apply the conv and pooling layers to obtain the feature map? The problem I find in this, is that the image I want to classify, may not have a similar feature map, and hence I wouldn't be able to find the distance correctly. As the order of the features may by different in the layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a fully connected layer at the end of the network and train it. After training, using a simple forward pass, you can classify your image.
image-->conv layer-->pool layer --> fully connected layer

Answer (score 0):

You can use restricted boltman machine to obtain feature map, and then build a CNN with this architecture : conv layer -> pooling->conv layer pooling-> ....->fully connected layer.   Add conv layer and pooling layer until the matrix size reduced into $1\times 1$, then treat them as input for your fully connected layer, then train the fully connected layer